# How to summarize values by key of an Erlang map list?

Tags: erlang

This is what my list of maps looks like:

```
Map = [#{votes=>3, likes=>20, views=> 100},#{votes=>0, likes=>1, views=> 70},#{votes=>1, likes=>14, views=> 2000}].
```

I would like to return a summary of all map entries. I have attempted to solve this with fun()s but the logic does not make sense, and I only got non-executeable code.

The problem is that one cannot change variables in Erlang, otherwise this would work:

```
Summary = #{
    votes=>0,
    likes=>0,
    views=>0,
},
[maps:update(Key, maps:get(Key, MapItem) + maps:get(Key, Summary), Summary) || MapItem <- Map, Key <- [votes, likes, views]].
```

How ought one go about this and successfully summarize the values of a list of maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions of `fold` family are designed to be used in such situations. In your case the following code calculates the map containing totals of entries in maps in the list:

```
MapsList = [#{votes=>3, likes=>20, views=> 100},
            #{votes=>0, likes=>1, views=> 70},
            #{votes=>1, likes=>14, views=> 2000}],
Summary = lists:foldl(fun (Map, AccL) ->
    maps:fold(fun (Key, Value, Acc) ->
        Acc#{Key => Value + maps:get(Key, Acc, 0)}
    end, AccL, Map)
end, #{}, MapsList)
```

`Summary` value is the map `#{votes => 4, likes => 35, views => 2170}`.